# include widget once?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm using yesod 0.9.3 with scaffolded site.  Is there any way to include some widget into resulting page only once (or, preferably, make some widget includable only once), like `addScript` and `addStylesheet` do?  I can call such (dependency) widgets in the page handler, but this breaks the whole idea of (dependent) widget as a self-contained entity which you just call when you need it.

Example:

```
addCommonStyle :: Widget
addCommonStyle = toWidgetHead [lucius|.some-class {background: yellow}|]

styledP :: Text -> Widget
styledP t = do
    addCommonStyle
    [whamlet|<p .some-class>#{t}|]

getTestR :: Handler RepHtml
getTestR = defaultLayout $ do
    styledP "First paragraph"
    styledP "Second paragraph"
```

This result in HTML with link to stylesheet containing

```
.some-class{background:yellow}.some-class{background:yellow}
```

that is, addCommonStyle is included twice.

Comment: If you include some code - or an exmaple of what your are attempting this will help people to answer your question

Comment: Have you seen instances where the widget is included twice?  My understanding was that Yesod ensures it's only there once.

Comment: @JeffFoster, I've added purified example

Comment: FYI, you dont need the `toWidgetHead` call, yesod will automatically stick styles in the `head`

Answer (score 1):

easiest solution is to just put `addCommonStyle` in the definition of `defaultLayout` in the `Foundation.hs` file.

If you dont always need it, you can just make your own layout function following the pattern in the scaffolded `defaultLayout` which includes the `addCommonStyle` call.

Comment: Quoting myself, "but this breaks the whole idea of (dependent) widget as a self-contained entity which you just call when you need it."

Comment: true, but with proper caching the impact of sending the style when its not used will be minimal